# Delete from cursor to end of line under visual selection in vim

Tags: vim

I have a code segment like below.

```
type Account struct {                                                                                                                                                                                       
    Id                         int                                                                                                                                                                          
    UserId                     int                                                                                                                                                                          
    Name                       string                                                                                                                                                                       
    Address                    string                                                                                                                                                                       
    City                       string                                                                                                                                                                       
    State                      string                                                                                                                                                                       
    CountryId                  string 
}
```

I want to delete all the data types. Is there a key combination to this?

I tried `<C-V>` and select the first letter of all data types in a vertical line, hoping `d + $` would work post that, however vim only takes the first input `d` and deletes the first letter.

Comment: Place the cursor on the first `int`, then use `<C-V>` to select all the data types, then simply `x`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `<C-v>` to enter visual block mode, select the lines you want to change and then `D` to delete until the end of those.

From `:h v_D` :

```
{Visual}["x]X   or                  *v_X* *v_D* *v_b_D*
{Visual}["x]D       Delete the highlighted lines [into register x] (for
                    {Visual} see |Visual-mode|).  In Visual block mode,
                    "D" deletes the highlighted text plus all text until
                    the end of the line.  {not in Vi}
```

Note that, as mentioned in the help, `X` and `D` are not equivalent in visual *block* mode (`X` only deletes the current selection, not until the end of the line).

Comment: Woah never thought of that. Perfect! Could you edit your answer to include `<C-V>` selection as well? I'll make it as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

You can move to the left brace, press the `%` key and issue:

```
s/ \+[^ ]* *$/
```

to get:

```
type Account struct
    Id
    UserId
    Name
    Address
    City
    State
    CountryId
}
```

The substitution removes all non-white-space characters at the end of the line.

Comment: This solution would be clearer and more complete with the use of \s and \S, to consider other kinds of whitespace, such as tabs: `s/\v\s+\S+\s*$/`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `C-V` and select the first column of all data type, then do `$` to select until the end of the line, followed by `x` or `d` to delete.

Answer (score 0):

1. Visually select all those lines with `v6j`.
2. Remove the extra stuff with `:'<,'>norm ElD` (`'<,'>` is added automatically for you).

Also, watch out for trailing space!

Answer (score 0):

Not the shortest possible sequence but following is more natural to me

- `vi{` *- Visually select the inner paragraph*
- `'<,'>norm weld$`  *(typed as :norm weld$)*

witch breaks down to

- `'<,'>norm` *- Apply normal commands over the selection*
- `wel` *- jump to the end of the first word*
- `d$` *- delete until the end of the  line*